# React-dates SDP - how to disable today?

Tags: react-dates

I'm using Airbnb's react-dates (SingleDatePicker) but I can't figure out how to disable today's date. Everything else is working great, I just don't want them to be able to select today.

Answer (score 1):

`isOutsideRange` expects a callback that receives as an argument a day of the calendar.

You should write a function to compare this argument with the day you want to block.
Example of a function

```
function blocksDay(day) {
  return day.isSame(moment(), ‘“day”);
}
....
<SingleDatePicker
...
isOutsideRange={blocksDay}
/>
```

`blocksDay` function executes for each day of the calendar, to know which days to allow.

You can block entire ranges, or just specific dates. This is thanks to `moment.js` library.
Here’s a link for the docs of moment: [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

You can test moment functions in browser if you want, just open the console of the browser when you’re at moment’s website